# How to match of exactly 1 in the set of [Test, Dev, Prod]?

Tags: regex

This is my code so far: `([T|t][E|e][S|s][T|t])|([D|d][E|e][V|v])|([P|p][R|r][O|o][D|d])`

I want to match only 1 of these set, example:

1. Test - Match
2. Test Test - not match
3. Test Dev - not match

Comment: What language or text editor?

Comment: I think the problem is you don't have ^ symbol at the beginning and $ at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the following regex:

```
/^(test|dev|prod)$/gim
```

Note the use of the [`i`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_i.asp) modifier, that make the regex case insensitive.

`^` and `$` ([`m`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_m.asp) modifier) are use to match the beginning and the end of the string, in order not to match `test test`, etc.

### [Test it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/m0kKKz/3)

Comment: Depending on the language used, you could mention the anchors `^` and `$`.

Comment: @BartKiers Thanks for your comment, you are right. I've updated my answer to add an explanation about `^`, `$` and the `m` modifier.

Comment: But now, with the `m` modifier, `^` and `$` don't match the start and end of the input, but the start and end of a line. In other words, the string `"Dev\nFOO"` would now also match. Not sure if the OP wants that, or is aware of it. I'd just suggest the pattern `/^(test|dev|prod)$/i`

Comment: Thanks so how can I start at any position for the regex? Example: sampletexthere DEV - MATCH?

Comment: What is the language? @RickyCuarez

Comment: It's kind of a special only used in IBM, it's Automation Anywhere. I'm not really sure what language it uses. but it just takes input of regular expressions.